# ActiveRecord query to return model with zero or more associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to query a course and return the course along with all of its events that have a startdate of somewhere in the future, so events could either be [] or more.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  scope :published_events, -> { where('events.starts > ?', Date.today).references(:events)}

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  scope :live, -> { where('starts >= ?', Date.today)}
```

I tried Course.includes(:events).published_events and Course.join(:events).published_events, but can't seem to get the behaviour I'm after.

The problem is when a course has no events in the future, the query returns nothing, whereas I still want to retrieve the course even if it has no events.

Comment: Do you get an error or just not the data you're after?

Comment: @Iceman: Just added this to the q: The problem is when a course has no events in the future, the query returns nothing, whereas I still want to retrieve the course even if it has no events.

Answer (score 0):

What does the query look like? I think its generating an `INNER JOIN` against events, which requires that one or more rows exist. You want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which would allow courses without events to be returned.

You might need to try this:

`Course.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN events ON events.course_id = courses.id").published_events`

Comment: That still returns nothing if there are no live events, here is the query: Course.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN events ON events.course_id = courses.id").published_events.find(40) and SQL log: SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" LEFT OUTER JOIN events ON events.course_id = courses.id WHERE (events.starts >= '2014-05-22') AND "courses"."id" = $1

Comment: Yes, your date check in the `where` clause is what is stopping the query from returning any records (Course records w/o Events). You can move the date check to the `ON` clause itself: `... LEFT OUTER JOIN events ON events.course_id = courses.id AND events.starts >= '2014-05-22'...` or you'll have to re-think your approach

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding another relation to Course, `live_events`:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :live_events, -> { where('starts >= ?', Date.today)}, class_name:'Event'
```

and including that in my query:

```
@course = Course.includes(:live_events).find(id)
```

Not sure if this is the optimal way of solving this particular issue so if there is a better way please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Rails 4:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  scope :published_events, -> { joins(:events).merge(Event.live) }

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  scope :live, -> { where('starts >= ?', Date.today)}
```

Comment: Still returns no records when there are no live events. Query is: Course.published_events.find(40) Generated SQL:
SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."course_id" = "courses"."id" WHERE (starts >= '2014-05-22') AND "courses"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 40]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Course with id=40 [WHERE (starts >= '2014-05-22')]